# When a bank enters a swap with a counterparty, when does it decide to use a OIS curve as its CSA Term, versus a counterparty specific "CSA Curve"?

Tags: swaps, credit-risk, ois-discounting

What determines whether a swap should be discounted against a standard OIS curve VS a 'custom' CSA curve specific to the swap's counterparty? (such custom curves are marked as spreads to some base curve by the bank's trading desk)?

Answer (score 3):

To trade a swap counterparties must have an ISDA Master Agreement drawn up and signed between themselves.

If collateral is to be exchanged that agreement will also contain a section called a CSA: a Credit Support Annex.

That documentation defines the types of collateral available to post as the liability holder: and the banks choice of discount curve will reflect these choices.

Comment: So it is decided at the start of the relationship, when the counterparty requests to trade derivatives with this bank and the bank's credit dept approves this counterparty.